# Tcl/Tk examples?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

[Tcl/Tk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) is a simple way to script small GUIs.

Can anyone give a nice example with a *button* and a *text* widget. When the button is pressed should a shell command be executed and the output piped to the *text* widget.

If you have other nice and clean examples for useful tasks, please add them too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a more complete example using fileevents. This will auto-scroll all the time. For usability purposes you probably only want to auto-scroll if the bottom of the text is visible (ie: if the user hasn't moved the scrollbar) but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader to keep this already long example from getting any longer.

```
package require Tk

proc main {} {
    if {[lsearch -exact [font names] TkDefaultFont] == -1} {
        # older versions of Tk don't define this font, so pick something
        # suitable
        font create TkDefaultFont -family Helvetica -size 12
    }
    # in 8.5 we can use {*} but this will work in earlier versions
    eval font create TkBoldFont [font actual TkDefaultFont] -weight bold

    buildUI
}

proc buildUI {} {
    frame .toolbar
    scrollbar .vsb -command [list .t yview]
    text .t \
        -width 80 -height 20 \
        -yscrollcommand [list .vsb set] \
        -highlightthickness 0
    .t tag configure command -font TkBoldFont
    .t tag configure error   -font TkDefaultFont -foreground firebrick
    .t tag configure output  -font TkDefaultFont -foreground black

    grid .toolbar -sticky nsew
    grid .t .vsb  -sticky nsew
    grid rowconfigure . 1 -weight 1
    grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1

    set i 0
    foreach {label command} {
        date     {date} 
        uptime   {uptime} 
        ls       {ls -l}
    } {
        button .b$i -text $label -command [list runCommand $command]
        pack .b$i -in .toolbar -side left
        incr i
    }
}

proc output {type text} {
    .t configure -state normal
    .t insert end $text $type "\n"
    .t see end
    .t configure -state disabled
}

proc runCommand {cmd} {
    output command $cmd
    set f [open "| $cmd" r]
    fconfigure $f -blocking false
    fileevent $f readable  [list handleFileEvent $f]
}

proc closePipe {f} {
    # turn blocking on so we can catch any errors
    fconfigure $f -blocking true
    if {[catch {close $f} err]} {
        output error $err
    }
}

proc handleFileEvent {f} {
    set status [catch { gets $f line } result]
    if { $status != 0 } {
        # unexpected error
        output error $result
        closePipe $f

    } elseif { $result >= 0 } {
        # we got some output
        output normal $line

    } elseif { [eof $f] } {
        # End of file
        closePipe $f

    } elseif { [fblocked $f] } {
        # Read blocked, so do nothing
    }
}


main
```

Comment: Would you like to give an python example that uses `fileevent` ?

Comment: @Thingamabobs: I don't think that would be appropriate here, the OP is asking for a Tcl solution.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

To append the output to the **text** widget, instead of specifying line 999999, you can use the index **end**, which refers to the position just after the last newline.  For example,

```
.main insert end "$x\n"
```

To have the text scroll as the command is outputting, use the **see** command.  For example, after appending to the .main text widget

```
.main see end
```

You may also want to consider grabbing the command output asynchronously, by using the **fileevent** command.

Answer (score 3):

I can give a start...please suggest improvements. I.e I'd like it to scroll as the command is outputting

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

proc push_button {} {
    put_text
    .main see end
}

proc put_text {} {
  set f [ open "| date" r]
  while {[gets $f x] >= 0} {
    .main insert end "$x\n"    
  }
  catch {close $f}
}

button .but -text "Push Me" -command "push_button"
text .main -relief sunken -bd 2 -yscrollcommand ".scroll set"
scrollbar .scroll -command ".main yview"

pack .but
pack .main -side left -fill y
pack .scroll -side right -fill y
```

Answer (score 2):

[wiki.tcl.tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/) is good website for all kinds of [examples](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1291)