# wxPython: execute command asynchronously, display stdout in text widget

Tags: wxpython

I'm looking for the wxPython equivalent to my answer for [Tcl/Tk examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166231/tcl-tk-examples). Specifically, I want to see an example of how to create several buttons, each of which runs some external command when clicked. While the process is running I want the output to go to a scrollable wxPython widget.

While the process is running the GUI should not block. Assume, for example, one of the buttons may kick off a development task like building or running unit tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you are, a complete working example.

```
import wx
import functools
import threading
import subprocess
import time

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None, -1, 'Threading Example')
        # add some buttons and a text control
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for i in range(3):
            name = 'Button %d' % (i+1)
            button = wx.Button(panel, -1, name)
            func = functools.partial(self.on_button, button=name)
            button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, func)
            sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.text = text
        sizer.Add(text, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    def on_button(self, event, button):
        # create a new thread when a button is pressed
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(button,))
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
    def on_text(self, text):
        self.text.AppendText(text)
    def run(self, button):
        cmd = ['ls', '-lta']
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        for line in proc.stdout:
            wx.CallAfter(self.on_text, line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That's a useful example, though not the same as the Tk example I mentioned in my question. This example ignores the part of my request where I say I want to run external commands. Yes, it's fairly easy to extrapolate from your example but I'm not sure a newbie stumbling on this example could figure it out. My hope in posting the question (besides quickly coming up to speed on wxPython) was to show the same small application in both languages. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)` , return utf-8 text.

Answer (score 0):

Start a thread when a button is clicked:

```
try:
    r = threading.Thread(target=self.mycallback)
    r.setDaemon(1)
    r.start()
except:
    print "Error starting thread"
    return False
```

Use wx.PostEvent and wx.lib.newevent to send messages from the callbacks to the main thread.

This [link](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-July/621566.html) may be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but I'm looking for a concrete example using wxPython.  Assume I know absolutely nothing about wxPython and you'll be very close to the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan,  try something like this:

```
import subprocess, sys

def doit(cmd):
    #print cmd
    out = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).stdout
    return out.read()
```

So when the button is pressed, the command gets run using the subprocess module, and you get the output as a string.  You can assign it to a Text Control's value to show it.  You might have to out.readfully()  or read multiple times to show text progressively.

If the button & text field aren't familiar, then a quick look at the [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#demo) will show you exactly what to do.

Comment: This doesn't meet one of my criteria: "While the process is running the GUI should not block". In your example the UI will block while you wait for out.read() to complete.

Comment: What makes you say that Bryan?  Have you tried it?  My understanding is you *can* make it block by doing a Popen.wait(), but if you don't block with the wait command, you'll be able to read whatever stdout is available at the time with the read command.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Bryan, this python stuff is a lot easier than you think it is... even easier than Tk if you give it a chance.

Comment: Why do I say ti blocks? Because if there's no output, the read will wait until there is output to read. Or do I misunderstand how read works?

Comment: @Jim: python is definitely not easier than tcl and tk (unless you know python and don't know tcl). Python might be equally easy as Tcl in many ways, but wxPython is certainly not as easy as Tk.

Comment: It's true.  I'm coming from a C / C++ & Objective-C systems-level GUI stuff, and wxPython seems so easy to me.  Python does have Tkinter, which you might prefer:  http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter.  subprocess is still the way to run a command and read from its stdin.  POpen object can also tell you if they've completed, so you don't block forever if there's no output.

Comment: One more comment... in the wxPython demo, search for process in the search box in the lower left.  It does an ASYNC run using wxWidget's approach.  I would still use the subprocess module, but other than that it's exactly what you're looking for.