# Developing for Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, qt, encoder

1. I want to develop multimedia encoder for Linux.
2. I want to make use of ready command line codecs like ffmpeg.
3. I want to build nice GUI for that & pass arguments to command line encoders.
4. I am thinking to use Qt.  (Is it possible?)
5. I don't know anything about Linux programming, but I have been an Ubuntu user for 8 months.

Please provide me with links to tutorials.  (I've tried the Ubuntu forums but it's all beginners stuff in there!)

I am in need of tips from you guys. I am ready to learn everything about it!

I am ready to learn new languages.

Thank you!

Comment: What languages do you know? Are you willing to learn more languages? What DE do you want to aim to?

Comment: Ya I am ready to learn new languages... I can spend 300 Hrs on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny story, actually. Two years ago, I developed this for a GTK frontend. You can grab the code at [vive.sourceforge.net](http://vive.sourceforge.net). I since abandoned it when nobody was using it and I had no need for it, anymore, but the code is still there and you're absolutely free to go tear it apart, laugh at my mistakes, and take what you can from it.

I will warn you, that code is fairly laughable. I was learning C and GTK at the time, so be easy on me :)

If you'd like to take it over, I'd be glad to turn it over!

It looked like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It Is Helpful. But I have some basic doubts....
I know c,c++,java programming (Can learn QT or GTK in a short time)
But I dont know how to create source for my project.
How to create that configure - make -make installable code?
Which tools should I use?

Comment: I used `automake` and `autoconf`, and that seemed to work out for me all right.

Comment: How much time will it take to create a project that beats avidemux?
(I can spend about 300 Hrs on it)