# Pipe command TCL

Tags: tcl

This subject was spoken many times and there is a lot of example on SO and the wiki, but I do not understand what's going on... in my case.
If I'm using `exec {*}$mycmd &` , my lines display in real time on my console and it is what I want , but I don't catch them , so I took an another approach and I  used `open |$mycmd r` but my lines display at the end of command.

```
% set mycmd [list $exe $journal -args {*}$args 2>c:/temp/error.txt]
% exec {*}$mycmd &
my line display in real time
my line display in real time
my line display in real time
...
...
...
%
```

my code with `pipeline`: [Fileevent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166231/tcl-tk-examples)

```
set in [open |$mycmd r]
fconfigure $in -blocking 0
fileevent $in readable [list handleFileEvent $in]
vwait ::forever

proc closePipe {f} {
    fconfigure $f -blocking true
    if {[catch {close $f} err]} {
        puts stderr $err
        set ::forever 1
    } else {
    set ::forever 1
    }
    }

proc handleFileEvent {f} {
    set status [catch { gets $f line } result]
    if { $status != 0 } {
        puts stderr $result
        closePipe $f
    } elseif { $result >= 0 } {
        puts stdout $line
    } elseif { [eof $f] } {
        closePipe $f
    } elseif { [fblocked $f] } {
        puts stdout $line
    }
}
```

Comment: stdout may be buffered. Try one of these: `flush stdout` after `puts stdout $line`; or `fconfigure stdout -buffering line`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman for the response , but same impact...

Comment: Are the procedure definitions really after the `vwait`? Or is that just how you happen to have written the question?

Comment: Also, if the subprocess writes directly to `/dev/tty` then you won't trap that with a simple pipeline. Some programs do that…

Comment: the procedure definition are before my command , just for my question :)  /dev/tty what is this ?

Comment: You don't have control of the buffering method used in $mycmd.   So what you want is going to be quite difficult.  You can try redirecting $mycmd output to a file and then having your Tcl program run a tail on it.  But the same issues will be present.

Comment: @BradLanam That sort of thing is fixable with `unbuffer`, a simple application of Expect…

Comment: ok , @DonalFellows Where i can find documentation or example ?